# Slack slash commands return http_client_error

Tags: flask, slack

I've got a python program which works just fine and is served by slack on port 5001 and when hit by a browser at http://ip:5001 results in the python program run by slack, a date/timestamp shown in the browser and a random file on /tmp hit with a /bin/touch to instantiate its timestamp to prove operability.

However, when using the Slack slash command mechanism, with the command

/whatever

with the request url

http://ip:5001

it produces this:

http_client_error

The message in the flask debug output live when I hit that ip and port is:

3.86.148.230 - - [11/Feb/2020 03:00:25] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 -

The ip is from AWS which is, presumably, one of the Slack servers....

It's not mine...

Thoughts?

Comment: If you need the python code flask is serving, let me know.